# SSIS Conditional split for different Datatypes in Identity Column

Tags: ssis

I need help: I have a identity column with both Numeric ( 23496)  and Alpha_numeric data (DATS_19202_GLE). I want to USE SSIS conditional Split transformation to split the data into two different tables e.g: if columnData have only Numeric data (23123) load data to "Table A" else load data to "Table B"

Thanks 
Cchris

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible with a simple SSIS Expression, you will need to try to cast the column in (DT_I4) for exemple and handle the error output.

Some exemple here : 
http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DustinRyan/ssis/915/check-isnumeric-with-derived-column-transform-in-ssis-package